# c++ generic object

Tags: c++

HI,

I have the following code:

```
class Libr
{   

public:
Libr();
std::string book;

class Street
{
public:
Street();

}*street
}*libr;
```

How can I use a generic object in the following method:

```
void find(std::string, ??generic object)
{//code};
```

Can someone please give me an example with the generic object applied for both the classes I wrote?THX!

Comment: You are making quite a few questions about *genericity* in the C++ language. I am getting the feeling that you are approaching the problems in the wrong way, c++ is not a dynamically typed language, and in many cases *genericity* will harm maintainability. You should really start from the basics with some tutorial and build from there up.

Comment: I agree. Yet it served me nicely, to test my generic skills. ;-) Anyway, I would be so kind to suggest to linuxx to have a look at a tutorial, such as: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a function template:

```
template<class T>
void find(std::string s, T & object)
{
    //code
};
```

You can call this with a parameter of any type. Read [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates) to get more on templates.

Comment: thx for the answer. What should the class T contain? and how should i call the find method from void main(). Don't i need an object to Libr and Street classes (in void main())?

Comment: could you please complete my code...witj you example and with how should i call these from void int().wish u a great weekend. Really appreciate.thx:)

Comment: @linuxx: `T` is a type-parameter. You can substitute any type for it. If you call `find` with an object of `int` as `object`, it will for instance become `void find(std::string, int &)`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can pass untyped pointer:

```
void find(std::string, void* object)
{
    //code
}
```

It depends on what you are going to do inside find().

Comment: If you're going to do almost any operation on **object**, comparison for instance, this approach requires you to know the type of the pointed-to object, and cast the void pointer to a pointer of that type. Thus **find** must know the dynamic type of object anyway. While there are contrived examples where you might do pointer comparisons instead of comparing objects, this approach has limited applicability.